# Configuring Kaggle for distributed training and memory sharing across two T4 GPUs

Tags: python, machine-learning, kaggle, distributed-training

I'm trying to train a Dreambooth using the following command on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/):

```
!accelerate launch --num_cpu_threads_per_process=2 "./sdxl_train.py" \
  --pretrained_model_name_or_path="stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0" \
  --train_data_dir="dataset/img" \
  --reg_data_dir="dataset/reg" \
  --output_dir="output" \
  --output_name="SDXLDreambooth" \
  --save_model_as="safetensors" \
  --train_batch_size=1 \
  --max_train_steps=8000 \
  --save_every_n_steps=4001 \
  --optimizer_type="adafactor" \
  --optimizer_args scale_parameter=False relative_step=False warmup_init=False \
  --xformers \
  --lr_scheduler="constant_with_warmup" \
  --lr_warmup_steps=100 \
  --learning_rate=2.5e-6 \
  --max_grad_norm=0.0 \
  --resolution="1024,1024" \
  --save_precision="fp16" \
  --save_n_epoch_ratio=1 \
  --max_data_loader_n_workers=1 \
  --persistent_data_loader_workers \
  --mixed_precision="fp16" \
  --full_fp16 \
  --logging_dir="logs" \
  --log_prefix="last" \
  --gradient_checkpointing \
  --caption_extension=".txt" \
  --no_half_vae \
  --cache_latents
```

and adding `--train_text_encoder` gives an out of memory error on a P100 GPU with 16 GB VRAM, even with all optimisations on. I've tested running the same command on an L4 GPU with 24 GB VRAM on [Modal](https://modal.com/), and it runs successfully with a maximal VRAM utilization of around 18 GB.

However, I've noticed Kaggle provides also the option of using two T4 GPUs with 16 GB VRAM each, which led me to wonder as to whether it's possible to alter the configuration of the environment there (including e.g. changing the script, the DeepSpeed configuration, the accelerate configuration, etc.) to allow memory sharing across the 2 GPUs, whose total combined memory (32 GB) should allow the command to run (which requires 18 GB of memory).

The default behaviour set by Kaggle seems to be to copy the configuration across the 2 GPUs and process the training in parallel, so with the `--train_text_encoder` option the script would require 18 GB of each GPU, leading to an out of memory error.

How should I configure the environment so as to allow for memory sharing across both GPUs, and avoid the out of memory error I'm receiving?

---

**Edit:** Here are some links to a sample notebook and some runs:

- [The notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/emilyyui/dreambooth-sdxl-example?scriptVersionId=161817873);
- [An OOM'd run with two 15 GB T4 GPUs](https://www.kaggle.com/code/emilyyui/dreambooth-sdxl-example/notebook);
- [A successful run with one 16 GB P100 GPU](https://www.kaggle.com/code/emilyyui/dreambooth-sdxl-example/notebook?scriptVersionId=161820873).

Neither of these have `--train-text-encoder` enabled, as it leads to an OOM error. Here's the memory utilization for the T4 GPUs in the first run:

[image: gpus]